# How to select an inline element using watir in ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath, cucumber, watir

I want the text "HEATMAPS" to be clicked after the webpage is opened. I have tried number of click methods, including recognizing as hyperlink, as text, as using xpath etc. None of them worked. I feel, I am either misunderstanding the links, as to be a hyperlink or choosing a wrong xpath.

[Link of the web page](http://app.vwo.com/#/analyze/analysis/108/summary?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D)

PFB the code below

```
 require 'watir-webdriver'
 require 'watir-ng'
 WatirNg.patch!
 WatirNg.register(:ng_scope).patch!
 browser = Watir::Browser.new
 browser.goto 'http://app.vwo.com/#/campaign/108/summary?   token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0='

 lin = browser.link :text=> 'HEATMAPS'
 lin.exist?
 lin.click
```

Can someone please guide me on this, as to how I can make that link with the text "HEATMAPS" in the page get clicked.

The error i get:

```
`This code has slept for the duration of the default timeout waiting for an Element to exist. If the test is still passing, consider using Element#exists? instead of rescuing UnknownObjectException
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-6.1.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:507:in `rescue in wait_for_exists': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:text=>"HEATMAPS", :tag_name=>"a"} to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-6.1.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:497:in `wait_for_exists'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-6.1.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:515:in `wait_for_present'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-6.1.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:533:in `wait_for_enabled'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-6.1.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:656:in `element_call'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-6.1.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:114:in `click'
        from C:/Users/Mrityunjeyan/Documents/GitHub/Simpleprograms/webautomation.rb:10:in `<main>'`
```

This would display me the inner_html text but still wouldnt click

`lin = browser.span(:class => 'ng-scope').inner_html
puts lin`

Comment: I have tried identitifying the element using `inner_html` and `innertext` too, but still doesnt work, that would display a `nomethoderror`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the link's text is not "HEATMAPS". It is actually "Heatmaps". The text locator is case-sensitive, which means you need:

```
lin = browser.link :text=> 'Heatmaps'
```

You can see this if you inspect the HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="campaign.heatmap-clickmap" href="#/analyze/analysis/108/heatmaps?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D">
  <!-- boIf: isAnalyticsCampaign -->
  <span bo-if="isAnalyticsCampaign" class="ng-scope">Heatmaps</span>
  <!-- boIf: !isAnalyticsCampaign -->
</a>
```

It only looks like "HEATMAPS" due to the styling. One of the styles includes a `text-transform: uppercase;` which visually capitalizes the text. Watir does not interpret the styles, so only knows that the text node is "Heatmaps".

Once you have identified the link, clicking still has a problem:

```
lin.click
#=> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
#=> unknown error: Element <a ui-sref="analyze.heatmaps" ng-class="{selected: (locationContains('analyze', 'heatmap') &amp;&amp; !locationContains('analyze', '/analysis') &amp;&amp; state.current.name !== 'campaign.heatmap-clickmap') || (isAnalyzeHeatmapEnabled &amp;&amp; (isAnalyzeDeprecatedHeatmapView || locationContains('analyze', '/analysis', 'heatmaps')) )}" data-qa="nav-main-analyze-heatmap" href="#/analyze/heatmap">...</a>
#=> is not clickable at point (90, 121).
#=> Other element would receive the click: <div ng-show="!isCROSetupView" class="">...</div>
```

The link being located is actually the one in the left menu, which is disabled, rather than the top menu. You need to scope the link locator to just the top menu. Using the parent `ul` element appears to be sufficient:

```
lin = browser.ul(class: 'page-nav').link(text: 'Heatmaps')
lin.click
```

To see the `click` complete, you might want to tell Chrome not to close at the end of the script. This is done by opening the browser using the following option:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {'detach' => true})
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Comment: Thanks! There is a progress now, I have been using the same command but with class `ng-scope` as it appeared nested in the `li`. Currently, I find the chrome is launching the page, and closing the page, without giving me any errors or output and neither it appears to click.

Comment: I even tried using
`lin = browser.ul(class: 'page-nav').link(text: 'Heatmaps')`
`lin.exist?`
`lin.click` 

Any idea why?

Comment: You might want to be careful about the class `ng-scope`. It's rather general and does not make it obvious what you are locating. It sounds like the code is working, however due to the asynchronous behaviour, Chrome is moving on before the new page is loaded. By default, Chrome closes at the end of the script. So if you have other code following, you won't see the page load. For debuggin, you should tell Chrome to stop closing at the end (see update).

Comment: Brother! You are amazing! Thanks a lot for this information. Have been draining my head in this for the last 2 days, I wish I could have come and asked here, but still, worth learning the challenges. Thanks a lot Justin!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your target link doesn't have any text</strike>. I confirmed with nokogiri that the text of the `<a>` tag includes the text inside the child `<span>` tag, and it turns out Watir works the same way.

If you use a Chrome browser, you can select:

```
View > Developer > Developer tools
```

Then you can select an element on the page, and the corresponding section in the html will be highlighted.  Here is what the html looks like:

```
<a ui-sref="campaign.heatmap-clickmap" 
   href="#/analyze/analysis/108/heatmaps?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D"> 
<!-- boIf: isAnalyticsCampaign -->

<span bo-if="isAnalyticsCampaign" class="ng-scope">Heatmaps</span> 

<!-- boIf: !isAnalyticsCampaign --> </a>
```

The basic structure is:

```
<a><span>Heatmaps</span></a>
```

Chrome even has a feature where you can right click on an element and get its xpath, which you can use with Watir.

However, when I execute my program to go to that page, I see Chrome launch, and then I'm presented with a login page rather than the page that was presented to me at your link.

**Arghhh...what a colossal waste of time.**  I thought Watir must be broken.  With the proper url, I can get the link using several different techniques:

1)

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-ng'   #<=NOTE THIS

WatirNg.register(:'bo_if').patch!  #<= NOTE THIS

br = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
br.goto 'http://app.vwo.com/#/analyze/analysis/108/summary?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D'

target_link = br.span(
  class: 'ng-scope',
  'bo_if': 'isAnalyticsCampaign', 
).parent  #<= NOTE THIS

puts target_link.text  #HEATMAPS
puts target_link.href  #http://app.vwo.com/#/analyze/analysis/1.....
```

2)

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-ng'  #<=NOTE THIS

WatirNg.register(:ui_sref).patch!  #<=NOTE THIS

br = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
br.goto 'http://app.vwo.com/#/analyze/analysis/108/summary?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D'

target_link = br.link(
  ui_sref: 'campaign.heatmap-clickmap',
  href: '#/analyze/analysis/108/heatmaps?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D'
)

puts target_link.text   #HEATMAPS
puts target_link.href   #http://app.vwo.com/#/analyze/analysis/108...
```

3)  Getting the xpath by right clicking on the link in Chrome:

```
require 'watir'

br = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
br.goto 'http://app.vwo.com/#/analyze/analysis/108/summary?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D'

target_link = br.link(
  xpath: '//*[@id="main-container"]/ul/li[3]/a'
)
puts target_link.text  #HEATMAPS
puts target_link.href  #http://app.vwo.com/#/analyze/analysis/108....
```

xpath can handle any tag or attribute name, unlike Watir, so it seems like a good tool in that regard.

4) A less brittle xpath:

```
require 'watir'

br = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
br.goto 'http://app.vwo.com/#/analyze/analysis/108/summary?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D'


a_href = "#/analyze/analysis/108/heatmaps?token=eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxNTA3MzQsImV4cGVyaW1lbnRfaWQiOjEwOCwiY3JlYXRlZF9vbiI6MTQ0NDgxMjQ4MSwidHlwZSI6ImNhbXBhaWduIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MSwiaGFzaCI6IjJmZjk3OTVjZTgwNmFmZjJiOTI5NDczMTc5YTBlODQxIn0%3D"

target_link = br.link(
  xpath: %Q{ //a[@href="#{a_href}"] } +
               '[@ui-sref="campaign.heatmap-clickmap"]' +
               '[child::span[@class="ng-scope"][@bo-if="isAnalyticsCampaign"][text()="Heatmaps"]]' 
)
```

The xpath looks for an `<a>` tag with two attributes:

```
//a[@href="blah"][@ui-sref="bleh"]
```

which has a child `<span>` (i.e. a direct child) with three attributes:

```
[child::span[@class="blih"][@bo-if="bloh"][text()="Heatmaps"]]
```

After I programmatically click the link:

```
target_link.click
```

Watir goes to the next page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get this, the structure, but my question was, what is the `element name` or `class name`, ill have to give to identify that element in my ruby code? I already have the html and the structure through the developer tools, inspect option.

However, When click on copy xpath, I get it is `//*[@id="main-container"]/ul/li[3]/a/span`


Not sure, why are you given a login page, since when I am executing the same code I mentioned in the question, each time, it opens up the dashboard.

Comment: The login page appears to occur due to the space in the URL (for the code sample). If you take out the space, it navigates as expected.

Comment: Okay! But still I find the code, not clicking the element, I specify. Were you able to do so?

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS, Yes--now that I have the proper url.  I posted a couple of solutions.

Comment: @7stud Nice, I did try `watir-ng`, but felt, again, I am using too many modules, and hence ruled out that approach. But still, the `xpath` approach was the first one I did, but didnt know the format of how the code needs to be done, to achieve the click. Ill note all these approaches for future reference. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JustinKo ^^ Can you help me with the locator again please? If it comes under `div tag`? I understand texts under `div tags` can be directly called and I tried doing that, by directly giving it a `.click` command by identifying as text, but still this wouldn't locate. PFB the code

`target_link = browser.link(`
 `xpath: '//*[@id="option-section"]/div[6]/img'`
`)`
`target_link.exist?`
`target_link.click`

Comment: Sorry @MrityunjeyanS, but I don't understand your question. I cannot tell what you are trying to interact with on the page. I'm not even sure the URL is working as I don't see a "player"? Note that if it is a different question, you should open a new question. Questions in comments are very difficult to read/follow/edit.

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS, I don't know what ***element list*** is, and when I paste your xpath into the search box, there are no matches at that url.

Comment: *u need to wait for sometime for the player to appear*--There's also nothing on the page that I can identify as a player.  It's like you gave the wrong url.

Comment: @7stud  Are you able to see in the bottom of the screen a kind of tool in grey, having four options in the bottom of the web page, and on the bottom right you have a text called "Element list" ?

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS, No.  That's not even close to what I see.  That looks similar to the first page you were dealing with.  On the other hand, the link  ankitagupta.wingified.com/?id=150734 takes me to a page with a white background, two google logos on top, and a bunch of lorem ipsum text.  And when I say, I can't find *element list* on the page, that means I used the find function to search for it, and it doesn't exist.  That doesn't mean I glanced at the page, and I didn't see it.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing at your url: http://picpaste.com/screen1_copy-NMnykTTI.png

Comment: @7stud Thanks a lot for the help till now :)